# MariaDB optimization and dump for a db over 1gb and 1500+ update operation per minute

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I'm wondering what optimization I can do in MariaDB for cache, allow more connection or anything to you suggest.
I just installed MariaDB on a clean digitaocean Ubuntu. (No optimization in mysql configuration) just indexing on db level.
Also, is it good to do a nightly dump of database while the update and select queries are running? (I'll need a major change in application to stop all queries to backup and then restart normal operation, I'm looking something to **gracefully backup without stopping any operation**)

Please let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Use InnoDB for all of *your* tables.
2. Use XtraBackup (from Percona).  (This *may* be better than regular `mysqldump`.)
3. Rest easy.

You will not lose any updates.  At worst, the updates and selects will be slower during the dump.  XtraBackup is better (I think) at being less invasive.

A more extreme solution is to set up Replication.  Then you would have a Master that you talk to, plus a Slave that is *continually* a "backup" (since it is a copy of the Master).

Some other things to check on:

- Did you change `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (How much RAM do you have?)
- Do the indexes help the `SELECTs`.  (Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a slow `SELECT`.)